# MonoGame - Drag and Drop

Tags: monogame

I am currently writing a game using the monogame framework. I am having trouble with reacting to the touch input correctly. I want the user to be able to drag the "objToDrag". The problem is that both deltaX and deltaY are always zero. Here is my code:

```
var touchState = TouchPanel.GetState();

foreach (var touch in TouchPanel.GetState())
{
  if (touch.State == TouchLocationState.Moved)
  {
    TouchLocation prevLoc;

    if (!touch.TryGetPreviousLocation(out prevLoc)) continue;

    float deltaX = touch.Position.X - prevLoc.Position.X;
    float deltaY = touch.Position.Y - prevLoc.Position.Y;

    this.objToDrag.X += deltaX;
    this.objToDrag.Y += deltaY;
  }
}
```

Comment: objToDrag doesn't have a position vector?

Comment: Did you try to read the current gesture with TouchPanel.ReadGesture instead of getting the previous one?

Answer (score 0):

Use the delta value to calculate how far your object should move, no need to calculate your own.

```
foreach (var touch in TouchPanel.GetState())
{
  if (touch.State == TouchLocationState.Moved)
  {
       TouchLocation prevLoc;

       if (!touch.TryGetPreviousLocation(out prevLoc)) continue;

       float deltaX = touch.Delta.X;
       float deltaY = touch.Delta.Y;

       this.objToDrag.X += deltaX;
       this.objToDrag.Y += deltaY;
    }
}
```